# Currency can't be coerced into Float

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a line of code causing a  headache;

```
@amount = Currency.convert(current_user.currency, "USD", transaction.amount)
```

it brings an error like this

```
Currency can't be coerced into Float
```

And the application trace looks like this;

```
app/models/currency.rb:8:in `*'
app/models/currency.rb:8:in `convert'
app/controllers/paypal_controller.rb:35:in `create'
```

where `Currency.convert`the model method looks like this

```
  def self.convert(from,to,amount)
    from_rate = Currency.find_by_currency(from)
    to_rate = Currency.find_by_currency(to)
    usd = (amount/(from_rate.value.to_f))
    result = (usd*(to_rate.value.to_f))     
    return result
  end
```

What could the error be?

running in the console

```
def convert(from,to,amount)
    from_rate = Currency.find_by_currency(from)
    to_rate = Currency.find_by_currency(to)
    usd = (amount/(from_rate.value.to_f))
    result = (usd*(to_rate.value.to_f))     
    return result
  end
```

and then;

`convert("UGX","KES", 2000).to_f.round(0`)

works.

The currency model looks like this;

```
class Currency < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :currency, :value

      def self.convert(from,to,amount)
        from_rate = Currency.find_by_currency(from)
        to_rate = Currency.find_by_currency(to)
        usd_value  = (amount/(from_rate.value.to_f))
        result = (usd_value.to_f * (to_rate.value.to_f))        
        return result
      end
end
```

Comment: Presumably the issue is with this line - `result = (usd*to_rate.value)`.  What happens if you rewrite it as result = (usd*(to_rate.value))`  If you print out `to_rate.value`, what do you get?

Comment: What is the class of `usd` and `to_rate.value`? It seems one of them might be a `Currency` object when you aren't expecting.

Comment: @Teeg   These are just variables assigned here in the method.

Comment: @user2963716 - Can you provide us the complete code for the Currency model? Or at least the line numbers?

Comment: @Chandranshu, i have added it. Take a look at it.

Comment: Please provide the migration also for the Currency class. I'm beginning to suspect that your RDBMS supports a currency data type and you have used it or have used decimal as the type.

Comment: @user2963716 yes, the `usd_value` is created in that method, but `to_rate.value` is not. It could be as Chandranshu said, something is ultimately giving you a `Currency` object at some point, perhaps the `.value` method. In addition to what Chandranshu said, I would also set a breakpoint (check out [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)) and do a `usd_value.class` and `to_rate.value.class` and see if either come out as `Currency`.